# Token-Based Authentication With AngularJS & NodeJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

So, I came up from this Token-Based Authentication With AngularJS & NodeJS [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/token-based-authentication-with-angularjs-nodejs--cms-22543).

Now I want to implement my own RESTful Api to my AngularJS. Here it is my RESTful Api: `http://amr2.mybluemix.net/getpop/list`
The response from JSON is like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "fe107409a330778c0e22ebd8e34ca8fd",
    "_rev": "2-292360cf343367741469397112ff9a82",
    "d": {
      "parentsite": "1",
      "siteID": "10001",
      "location": "",
      "domain": "@test",
      "users": {
        "0": {
          "user": "admin@test",
          "pass": "12345",
          "level": 0
        },
        "1": {
          "user": "view@test",
          "pass": "12345",
          "level": 1
        }
      },
      "readpoint": {
        "0": {
          "uSN": "100010001",
          "metername": "demokit",
          "activedate": ""
        },
        "1": {
          "uSN": "100010002",
          "metername": "demokit2",
          "activedate": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I want to authenticate whether it is admin@test or view@test whose login to my angular.

This is `<body>` in my index.html

```
<body ng-app="angularRestfulAuth">

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" data-ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Angular Restful Auth</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a ng-href="#/">Home</a></li>
                    <li data-ng-show="token"><a ng-href="#/me">Me</a></li>
                    <li data-ng-hide="token"><a ng-href="#/signin">Signin</a></li>
                    <li data-ng-hide="token"><a ng-href="#/signup">Signup</a></li>
                    <li data-ng-show="token"><a ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" ng-view="">

    </div> <!-- /container -->

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/ngStorage.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/loading-bar.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/services.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is services.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularRestfulAuth')
    .factory('Main', ['$http', '$localStorage', function($http, $localStorage){
        var baseUrl = "https://amr2.mybluemix.net/getpop/list";
        function changeUser(user) {
            angular.extend(currentUser, user);
        }

        function urlBase64Decode(str) {
            var output = str.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');
            switch (output.length % 4) {
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 2:
                    output += '==';
                    break;
                case 3:
                    output += '=';
                    break;
                default:
                    throw 'Illegal base64url string!';
            }
            return window.atob(output);
        }

        function getUserFromToken() {
            var token = $localStorage.token;
            var user = {};
            if (typeof token !== 'undefined') {
                var encoded = token.split('.')[1];
                user = JSON.parse(urlBase64Decode(encoded));
            }
            return user;
        }

        var currentUser = getUserFromToken();

        return {
            save: function(data, success, error) {
                $http.post(baseUrl + '/signin', data).success(success).error(error)
            },
            signin: function(data, success, error) {
                $http.post(baseUrl + '/authenticate', data).success(success).error(error)
            },
            me: function(success, error) {
                $http.get(baseUrl + '/me').success(success).error(error)
            },
            logout: function(success) {
                changeUser({});
                delete $localStorage.token;
                success();
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

This is controller.js

```
'use strict'; 

angular.module('angularRestfulAuth')
    .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', '$localStorage', 'Main', function($rootScope, $scope, $location, $localStorage, Main) {

        $scope.signin = function() {
            var formData = {
                email: $scope.email,
                password: $scope.password
            }

            Main.signin(formData, function(res) {
                if (res.type == false) {
                    alert(res.data)    
                } else {
                    $localStorage.token = res.data.token;
                    window.location = "/";    
                }
            }, function() {
                $rootScope.error = 'Failed to signin';
            })
        };

        $scope.signup = function() {
            var formData = {
                email: $scope.email,
                password: $scope.password
            }

            Main.save(formData, function(res) {
                if (res.type == false) {
                    alert(res.data)
                } else {
                    $localStorage.token = res.data.token;
                    window.location = "/"    
                }
            }, function() {
                $rootScope.error = 'Failed to signup';
            })
        };

        $scope.me = function() {
            Main.me(function(res) {
                $scope.myDetails = res;
            }, function() {
                $rootScope.error = 'Failed to fetch details';
            })
        };

        $scope.logout = function() {
            Main.logout(function() {
                window.location = "/"
            }, function() {
                alert("Failed to logout!");
            });
        };
        $scope.token = $localStorage.token;
    }])

.controller('MeCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', 'Main', function($rootScope, $scope, $location, Main) {

        Main.me(function(res) {
            $scope.myDetails = res;
        }, function() {
            $rootScope.error = 'Failed to fetch details';
        })
}]);
```

This is app.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularRestfulAuth', [
    'ngStorage',
    'ngRoute',
    'angular-loading-bar'
])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }).
        when('/signin', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/signin.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }).
        when('/signup', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/signup.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }).
        when('/me', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/me.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$location', '$localStorage', function($q, $location, $localStorage) {
            return {
                'request': function (config) {
                    config.headers = config.headers || {};
                    if ($localStorage.token) {
                        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $localStorage.token;
                    }
                    return config;
                },
                'responseError': function(response) {
                    if(response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
                        $location.path('/signin');
                    }
                    return $q.reject(response);
                }
            };
        }]);

    }
]);
```

Can anybody show me what i have been missing and how to fix it?

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Your question is a bunch of code without a clear problem so that what's the problem?

Comment: @rob The code doesn't work. how to make this authentication works by consuming restful api?

Comment: @EugeneObrezkov The code doesn't work. how to make this authentication works by consuming my restful api?